# Is there a single word that means "cause(s) of death"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, vocabulary

It seems like this word exists, but maybe it's because I know it in another language (non-Romance) that I thinking it exists. I'm drawing a blank on it. I'd like to write a sentence that says "He listed the [causes of death]: ...."

Comment: what non-English word do you know?

Comment: It's 死因 (shiin) in Japanese (and possibly also in Chinese).

Comment: I looked for the phrase "cause of death" in the OED, and it appears in the definitions of ten words. However none of those are a headword for which "cause of death" is the definition. It would appear that there isn't one. If there were, I would expect it to start *mort-* and it doesn't list anything relevant.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I wasn't blanking on the word. It just doesn't (commonly) exist. Still, I have that vague feeling of dissatisfaction knowing that a word should exist, but doesn't.

Comment: @Jiken, technically that's a compound word so it isn't exactly a single word.

Comment: @Jiken: Just because other languages might have a single (or "compound") word for something doesn't mean English should as well. I think we've had "cause of death" on British death certificates for a *long* time now, and officialdom (which generally favours single-word terminology) hasn't seen fit to replace that with some obscure Graeco-Roman term.

Comment: If no one comes up with an existing term, I suggest the neologism ***mortifactor***.

Comment: @bib Excellent suggestion. I shall use it at my earliest convenience.

Answer (score 11):

Yes: *killer*.[¹](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=cause%20of%20death&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=100) For example, the following two sentences are nearly synonymous:

> Heart disease is the biggest *killer* in the United States.
>   Heart disease is the biggest *cause of death* in the United States.

As with all synonymous terms, there are subtle differences of tone. *Cause of death* is more neutral or formal. *Killer* has a more forceful impact, as it is also used in contexts where it suggests *murderer*.[²](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=killer)

Answer (score 4):

*Killer* is a good word, as another answerer has suggested.  If you like quaint Saxon words, as I do, then there is also the word *bane.*  (However, you can get away with writing words like that only if your English is very fluent.  The word *bane* probably has no place in journeyman-level international English, where *killer* is the better word.  If a Japanese wrote *bane* to me, I should immediately wonder if he had not mistyped some other word.  To gauge the matter, consider the unlikelihood that the word *bane* would occur in any English-language life-insurance policy of the 20th or 21st century, but rather *killer* or, regrettably more likely, *cause of death.*)

Comment: It's a shame how languages decay, really.  Endings are worn off words such that extra words become necessary to say the same thing with less precision (compare Spanish to classical Latin).  Deep, one-syllable words like *bane* disappear but from poetry.  It is unfortunate.

Comment: I should hasten to add, however, that the word *bane,* though quaint and grown rare, is still current and can still be used with care.

Comment: *Bane* is a lovely word from a whole family of related lovely words: including *autobahn*, *gonfalon*, *bezoar*, *antimony*.

Comment: Ha! Thanks to @MετάEd for that comment—I never knew ‘bezoar’ was basically the ‘killing father’, so to speak. Most interesting! ‘Antimony’, though?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Monk's bane". Just wondered if anybody was paying attention. :D

Comment: @MετάEd, sneaky! Didn’t know about the French folk-etymology of that, either.

Answer (score 1):

C.O.D. Not a word but a common abbreviation.

Comment: Mostly American crime dramas. I've heard it in numerous television series in the USA.

Comment: I think I've only ever heard this as an acronym for Call of Duty, so...use with caution.

Comment: This is a very common shipping abbreviation for "cash on delivery".

Answer (score 0):

***Mortefacient*** would be a technically appropriate neologism

-facient from L. facere, to cause

Answer (score 0):

Both  [lethal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lethal?s=t) and [mortal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mortal?s=t) are applicable in the context you are proposing?

- He listed the following lethal/mortal factors/agents.

If you are pedantic about a single word then there's none better than the neologism I proposed earlier.